# onLocationChanged not working, it seams that is not called

Tags: android, google-maps

I am pretty new to android, I'm working on an school project where I have to use google maps. Also I have to track the user location and when location is changed, I have to update user location in database. So far I managed to integrate gmaps and I'm working now on location change. I implement the interface LocationListener on my class, also I overrided onLocationChanged method, which seams that is not working. What I'm missing? Thank you!

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener, DialogManager.OnDialogListener {

private GoogleMap gMap;
private SupportMapFragment smf;
private View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    smf = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mainContent);
    if (smf == null) {
        smf = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, smf).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!LocationUtils.getInstance().isGPSON(this.getActivity())) {
        DialogManager.buildAlertMessageNoGps(this.getActivity(), this);
    } else {
        if(smf!=null) {
            gMap = smf.getMap();
            if(gMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    Location location = LocationUtils.getInstance().getLastKnownLocation(this.getActivity());
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here!")); //this works, but it put  the market on the last known location, not where is my current gps location ..
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));

    List <Address> adr = LocationUtils.getInstance().getAddress(latLng, this.getActivity());
    String str = adr.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city   = adr.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    String coutry= adr.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"str: "+ str+"\ncity: "+city+"\ncountry: "+country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"sssCHANGEDsss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //this never appear
    if(gMap != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("updated!")); //marker title never updates
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
    }
}

@Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case DialogManager.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the requestLocationUpdates to get location updates. Use this in your setup map function along with your other functions.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"sssCHANGEDsss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //this never appear
    if(location != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("updated!")); //marker title never updates
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
    }

    }
};
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1.0f, locationListener);
```

update: I just noticed that you are implementing the LocationListerner to your activity also. If you are planning to use the above solution, then no need to implement LocationListener to the Activity. On a broader perspective, especially when you need location updates through out the app, create a custom location listener class. un couple from the activities and use wisely.

And don't forget to add ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions to your AndoidManifest.xml.

Comment: I added these permissions in my manifest. But am I doing something wrong in my code? Is not ok to implement  LocationListener?

Comment: Please check the first part. You were not using requestLocationUpdates function.
It is okay to implement locationlistener too. In that case, while requesting updates use the instance of your class.
   In that case I think you can use this (not tested though)locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1.0f, (android.location.LocationListener) this);

Comment: the app is crassing. I receive this error .... ui.fragments.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener

Comment: For this error, try replacing Fragment with FragmentActivity and can use  getSupportFragmentManager()  to access the features and resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"sssCHANGEDsss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //this never appear
    if(location != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("updated!")); //marker title never updates
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
    }
}
```

Comment: If toast never appears... I think the method is not called